# Why won't my React Native app display the images on Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new to React Native, coding an app for web and android. On web, my images display fine. On Android, *some* of them don't show. jpgs etc display fine but the images I need are .avif and they do not. Just a blank space shows in place of the image.

```
const imageSrc = "https://grocer-img.sgp1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/products/4781330397012883.avif"

 <Image source={{
     uri: imageSrc,
     }}
     style={styles.productImage}
     resizeMethod="resize"
  ></Image>
```

```
productImage: {
    width: "90%",
    aspectRatio: 1,
  }
```

Does anyone know how I can get my images to work on both web and android?

I've tried using a locally stored .avif to test and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing with Android OS less than version 12, the AVIF image format is not supported - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features#avif